# Unexpected ImportError

Tags: python, import

I don't understand why Python throws an exception in this case. I try to import from a *package* installed globally while there's a file with the same prefix as the package name. What am I missing?

```
$ touch fabric.py
$ python2
...
>>> from fabric.api import run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named api
```

Answer (score 0):

From Python documentation:

> This name will be used in various phases of the import search, and it may be the dotted path to a submodule, e.g. foo.bar.baz. In this case, ***Python first tries to import foo, then foo.bar, and finally foo.bar.baz. If any of the intermediate imports fail, an ModuleNotFoundError is raised.***

So, `import fabric.api` try to load your `fabric.py` first and succeeds, because it find your `fabric.py` file. Next it tries to load `api` in what it just loaded and that doesn't work.

So your `fabric.py` is shadowing the `fabric` global package.

More details here: http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/import.html

Comment: It's not "import fabric", its "import fabric.api" which implies hierarchy

Comment: @planetp I editied my answer and tried to make it a bit more complete :)

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. The hardest part is to forget my Perl background :)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a path of locations to look for modules: `sys.path`

```
['', ..., '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rsa-3.1.1-py2.7.egg', ..., 
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', ...]
```

It searches for matching modules from left to right.

So it first finds the local module.
This has no attribute `api`.

It would be not obvious if the local module was imported and the site-packages sub module was imported as its sub module.

Comment: So `module.submodule` can either be a module with an attribute or a package?